# How to take a partial derivative

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I want to check that I understand this correctly before heading off to the exam.

If $z = \sin(xe^y)$ where $x = 3u^2 + uv$ and $y = u^3 - \ln(v)$  find $\displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$

I have this:

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} = \displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \cdot \displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \sin(xe^y) = x^y\cos(xe^y)$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} 3u^2 + uv = 6u + v$

\begin{align}
\displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} &= \displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \cdot \displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\\
&= x^y\cos(xe^y) .(6u + v)\\
&= (3u^2 + uv)^{u^3 - \ln(v)}\cos((3u^2 + uv)e^{u^3 - \ln(v)}) .(6u + v)
\end{align}

This still needs some simplification, but is this the correct approach?

Comment: $$\partial_u z = \partial_x z \partial_u x + \partial_u z \partial_u y $$

Comment: Note that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\sin(x e^y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin^2(x e^y)$, and not what you want

Comment: @oholmer, wouldn't $\displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \sin(xe^y) = e^y\cos(xe^y)$? Because the $e^y$ is a constant when we take the derivative with respect to $x$. Then it pops out from the chain rule.

Comment: What I mean is $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin(x e^x) \ne \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\sin(x e^x)$

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that this question is still unanswered.
$$
\partial_u z = \partial_x z \partial_u x  + \partial_y z \partial_u y 
$$
where 
$$
z = \sin\left(x\mathrm{e}^y\right),\\
x = 3u^2 + uv,\\
y = u^3 - \ln(v).
$$

this leads to
$$
\partial_x z = \mathrm{e}^y\cos(x\mathrm{e}^y),\\
\partial_y z  = x\mathrm{e}^{y}\cos(x\mathrm{e}^y).
$$
for the partials w.r.t u of the variables x and y we use implicit differentiation.
$$
\partial_u x = 6u + v,\\
\partial_u y = 6u^2.
$$

Then 
$$
\partial_u z = \mathrm{e}^y\cos(x\mathrm{e}^y)*(6u + v) + x\mathrm{e}^{y}\cos(x\mathrm{e}^y)*(6u^2)\\
=\mathrm{e}^y\cos(x\mathrm{e}^y)\left[6u + v + x6u^2\right]
$$
Now i don't like to leave the result in terms of the original variables, so
$$
\partial_u z = \dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{u^3}}{v}\sqrt{1-z^2}\left[6u + v + 6(3u^2+uv)u^2\right]\\
= \dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{u^3}}{v}\sqrt{1-z^2}\left[6u\left(1 + 3u^3\right) + v\left(1+6u^3\right)\right]
$$

p.s I hope your exam went well :).